# 3 pin wire to desktop

Tags: desktop-computer

How do you call this kind of wire? I need to replace it and I've been searching on amazon everything from 3 pin to desktop power I can not get the right term. Where could I buy such?
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've got the name right, it is called **3-pin** connector.

You may also find references to it by:

- [3 pin fan connector](http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_ss_i_0_14?url=search-alias=electronics&field-keywords=3%20pin%20fan%20connector&sprefix=3%20pin%20fan%20conn,electronics,392)
- [3-Pin ATX](http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_ss_i_0_14?url=search-alias=electronics&field-keywords=3%20pin%20fan%20connector&sprefix=3%20pin%20fan%20conn,electronics,392#/ref=nb_sb_noss?url=search-alias=electronics&field-keywords=3-Pin%20ATX&rh=n:172282,k:3-Pin%20ATX)
- [3-Pin Fan](http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_ss_i_0_14?url=search-alias=electronics&field-keywords=3%20pin%20fan%20connector&sprefix=3%20pin%20fan%20conn,electronics,392#/ref=nb_sb_noss_2?url=search-alias=electronics&field-keywords=3-Pin%20Fan&rh=n:172282,k:3-Pin%20Fan)

Here's an [Amazon Search](http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_ss_i_0_14?url=search-alias=electronics&field-keywords=3%20pin%20fan%20connector&sprefix=3%20pin%20fan%20conn,electronics,392#/ref=nb_sb_noss?url=search-alias%3Delectronics&field-keywords=3-pin+connector&rh=n%3A172282%2Ck%3A3-pin+connector) for it.

Answer (score 2):

I'd call it a 3-pin fan connector.

http://www.allpinouts.org/index.php/Motherboard_(CPU)_3_Pin_Fan_Connector